# QML access to non invocable functions

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, qtscript

I need access to functions that wasn't marked as Q_INVOKABLE nor Q_SLOTS.
Qt script module has mechanism called [defaultPrototype](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/script-defaultprototypes.html). I wonder if it possible in QML?

I saw QtDevDays presentatin [QtDD12 - QtQuick under the hood - Thomas McGuire](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtXSaYpqaSQ)  and at 18 minute Thomas shows pure QML widget application. I think you cannot achieve it without exporting/exposing some non-invokable functions to script environment.

Is there any mechanism in QML like defualtPrototype in QtScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QML uses Qt Script under hood, so using the default prototype mechanism is perfectly possible. Only problem is obtaining the script engine of a declarative engine as their is no obvious API for that. Have look at the [code](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdelibs/repository/revisions/master/entry/experimental/libkdeclarative/kdeclarative.cpp) in libkdeclarative, especially `KDeclarative::initialize()`, for a viable hack to do so.

Comment: Actually it works partially. Prototype doesn't work for objects instantiated by QmlEngine, but works for objects instantiated in JavaScript.